# Is there a way of making a copy of the vector to template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Im trying to make a copy of the vector V.

I need to make a copy in the template (located as a comment) because im testing the running time of sort in this bechmark.

To make sure that a correct test of the sort running time is made, i need to make a copy because a running time of a sorted vector is different of the unsorted vector.

```
template <typename TFunc> void RunAndMeasure(const char* title,  const int repeat, TFunc func)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i) {
        //makecopyhere
        const auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        func();
        const auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << title << ": " << chrono::duration <double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << " ms" << "\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
}

int main()
{

    long int samples=5000000;
    constexpr int repeat{10};
    random_device rd;
    mt19937_64 mre(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> urd(1, 10);
    vector<int> v(samples);


    for(auto &e : v) {
        e = urd(mre);
    }


    RunAndMeasure("std::warm up", repeat, [&v] {
            vector <int> path= v;
            sort(execution::par, path.begin(), path.end()); 
            });



return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my poor english

Thank you

Comment: A copy of which vector?

Comment: I don't get the question.  You already make a copy of the vector in every call to `func()`

Comment: `vector <int> path= v;` creates a copy. Do you need another one?

Comment: Why not add one additional parameter to `RunAndMeasure` i.e. `vector<int>` to be sorted ? Then before calling `now` as start point of measuring time you would make a copy of that vector.

Comment: I want to remove the copy made in the fuction (vector path)  and make a copy in the template only to mesure the sort operation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove the copy made in the fuction (vector path) and make a copy in the template only to mesure the sort operation time.

So, something like

```
template <typename TFunc, typename TArg> void RunAndMeasure(const char* title,  const int repeat, TFunc func, TArg arg)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i) {
        TArg copy = arg;
        const auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        func(copy);
        const auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << title << ": " << chrono::duration <double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << " ms" << "\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    long int samples=5000000;
    constexpr int repeat{10};
    random_device rd;
    mt19937_64 mre(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> urd(1, 10);
    vector<int> v(samples);


    for(auto &e : v) {
        e = urd(mre);
    }

    RunAndMeasure("std::warm up", repeat, [](vector<int> & path) {
            sort(execution::par, path.begin(), path.end()); 
            }, v);

    return 0;
}
```